# Can my wife go to Ireland with EEA family visa from UK

Tags: visas, family

We have to go to my mother's funeral . My wife has EEA family visa valid till September.Can she travel to Ireland with the EEA Family visa. Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on some factors you haven't disclosed: Where are you traveling from? What is your anticipated mode of transportation? What is your nationality (specifically, the law is different depending on whether you are on the one hand Irish or on the other hand a national of another EU or Schengen state)?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.